# passing values from One controller to another Controller using Session or TempData not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have integrated payment gateway now, on success URL I want to pass some data from one controller to another controller but it's not working properly it's showing null value sometimes so, What I have to use instead of Session or TempData.

```
public void Index(UserRegistreModel model)
{        
    TempData["model2"]= model;
redirecturl += "&return=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();
}

public ActionResult AnotherControllerMethod(UserRegistreModel model)
{
UserRegistreModel add = (UserRegistreModel) TempData["model2"];
//not getting any values
}
```

Comment: I just changed my code can you please review again...because on adding return RedirectToAction("AnotherControllerMethod", "ControllerName", new { model = model });  it showing me the error returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Comment: On changing, Action return type it says not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How u are Passing Data ? Is it a forward or redirect? Forward will take the current data of your Request Object as it is the same Request but ur URL will not be changed in client.

And If u are redirecting then its a new Request. In This case the response will go to the client first (browser) then come to your new controller. As it is a new request, it will not have the old data from your calling controller.

Spring Has a special type of pojo called `RedirectAttributes`  for this. Where you can add `FlashAttribute` for this type of requirement. Check the similar thing in .net

Answer (score 1):

Your are adding  User type class to Temp Data but you are extracting UserRegistreModel type so, that's why this was empty, Use like this :-

```
public void Index(User model)
{        
  TempData["model2"]= model;
  redirecturl += "&return=" + 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();
}

public ActionResult AnotherControllerMethod(User model)
{
   User add = (User) TempData["model2"];
  //not getting any values
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how you r calling your Index function

Comment: <appSettings><add key="SuccessURL" value="http://localhost:47878/Return/AnotherControllerMethod"/>  </appSettings>